# Specifying a size when declaring a List of Arrays

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list

As the question states, is there an alternate way to do this?:

```
decimal[] decimal_array = new decimal[12];
List<decimal> decimal_list = new List<decimal>(3);

// want to combine the two
List<decimal[]> decimal_list_array = new List<decimal[12]>(3); // doesn't compile
```

I understand that this won't work because "decimal[12]" isn't a type, but it would be nice and concise to set the size of the structure when I declare it, instead of having to write `decimal_list_array.Add(new decimal[12])` a bunch of times.

I want to be able to operate primarily by index on each *instance* of an object in the list, but otherwise I don't care about ordering of the actual objects *in* the list.

Edit: The initial size of the structure will be known when declared, but this is just the minimum # of instances of the `List<decimal[]>`

Comment: I think that's the point of asking the question. Plus, I updated the question to reflect that though the decimal[] array size will be static, the List will be mutable. The declaring size is just the minimum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `LINQ`

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => new decimal[12]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to constrain the size of the inner array and outter list, then perhaps what you need is a [multi-dimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) instead.

```
decimal[,] decimalListArray = new decimal[3,12];
```

As you said, `new List<decimal[12]>(3)` won't work because `decimal[12]` is not a type, but even if it did, you're not actually constraining the list to have 3 elements either. 3 will be the *initial* capacity, but if a fourth item is added, the capacity will grow. Lists are dynamic by definition.

Comment: That's fine. I did neglect to mention that this structure isn't static in both the declaring size and ending size. I'll update the question.

Comment: @glace Ah, it did seem like that's what you were hinting at. Selman22's answer is the way to go then :)

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your input though, it was my mistake for not specifying the nature of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
decimal[] dec_array = new decimal[12] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
List<decimal> dec_list = new List<decimal>(3) { 12, 13, 14 };

List<decimal> listComb = dec_array.ToList().Union(dec_list).ToList();
//you can change order by doing so: dec_list.Union(dec_array.ToList()).ToList();
```

don't forget to 'using System.Linq;'